# Passing token as a parameter in http header

Tags: android

How to pass authentication token as a parameter in http header through android application? I have stored the token value in shared preference and trying to send but it is not happening. Please help.

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Post your code also.

Comment: @PiyushGupta Kai kam hatu ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pass your authentication token overriding the method `getHeaders()` from the Volley library like it is shown here http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/ in the chapter Setting Request Headers (HTTP headers)